# Is there a classical mechanism for gas heating by incident IR?

Tags: electromagnetism, infrared-radiation

Consider a cold gas in an otherwise empty chamber.

The gas is then illuminated with a narrowband MWIR coherent source. Let us ignore kinetic interactions with the chamber walls.

Is there a classical mechanism for the gas to heat?

In QM we understand it would depend on absorption lines of the gas and incident photon wavelength etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classically, the charges within each gas molecule would be subjected to a time-oscillating force at the frequency of the EM wave. It would then respond in accordance with the standard laws of resonance, gaining energy in an oscillatory mode. This energy would then be transferred to other modes of energy (kinetic & rotational, as well as being redistributed among the different oscillatory modes) via collisions with other gas molecules & via non-linearities in the restoring forces.

Comment: Lovely explanation thankyou :)  May I please ask, 1) what is meant by 'different oscillatory modes' and is that within the collective gas or within a single atom?  2) Can we think of the kinetic gain as the atom's charges "slingshot" off the EM wave's force? 3) Are the non-linearities in the restoring forces within the atom or the collective gas? Thanks!

Comment: @deeko 1)  Within a single *molecule*, not a single atom.   Look up [molecular vibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_vibration).  2)  A neutral molecule would not experience very much force from an EM wave, since it has no net charge.  (There would be small effects from permanent or induced dipoles, but they wouldn't be as big as the forces on a charged molecule would be.  3) Both options.  The main point is that if the forces are strictly linear, then all the modes of motion are independent and energy can't "leak" from one into another.

Comment: Marvelous thank you! :)